# Pyspark combine rows where column value is same

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark data frame that looks like this (It cannot be assumed that the data will always be in the order shown. Also total number of services is also unbounded while only 2 are shown in the example below):

```
| service | usage | count |
|---------|-------|-------|
|   a     |  low  |   5   |
|   a     | high  |   3   |
|   b     | high  |   3   |   
|   b     | low   |   2   |
```

I want to create a new dataframe where each row has the count of service's usage in string format. For example:

```
| service |       info       |
|---------|------------------|
|   a     |{low: 5, high: 3} |
|   b     |{low: 2, high: 3} |
```

Here's what I tried:

```
# data is originally in dataframe called df:
new_df = df.groupBy('service').agg(F.collect_list('count').alias('info'))
```

but the output for the above is this:

```
| service |       info       |
|---------|------------------|
|   a     |       [5,3]      |
|   b     |       [3,2]      |
```

The issue here is that the order of numbers in `info` column does not tell me which number corresponds to `high` and which to `low` usage. Also, there's no label present.

Comment: `collect_list` returns just a list of that column, with no other information, yes (you dropped the usage column). Did you try printing the grouped dataframe?

Comment: yes, `new_df.show()` displays the output table I pasted above.

Comment: @cliqer Is there a finite number of usage categories? And do you know those categories in advance?

Comment: @ksgj1 Yes, usage categories are finite and known in advance: `low` and `high` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here requires knowing the categories in `usage` in advance.
The idea here is to use `pivot` to get the `low`/`high` columns, then convert it to a struct which you can then turn into a JSON string.

We start with this data frame

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame({
        "service": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"],
        "usage": ["low", "high", "high", "high", "low", "low"],
        "count": [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1],
    })
)
```

```
+-------+-----+-----+
|service|usage|count|
+-------+-----+-----+
|      a|  low|    5|
|      a| high|    3|
|      a| high|    3|
|      b| high|    2|
|      b|  low|    4|
|      c|  low|    1|
+-------+-----+-----+
```

Since you didn't specify in your question, I'm assuming a general case where `(service, usage)` is not unique (see `a`), and if "usage" is not complete for a given "service" (see `c`).

---

The solution:

```py
(
    df
    .groupBy("service")
    .pivot("usage", values=["low", "high"])
    .agg(
        F.max("count").alias("count"),
    )
    # -------- (1)
    .select(
        "service",
        F.to_json(F.struct(
            col("low").alias("low"),
            col("high").alias("high"),
        )).alias("info"),
    )
    .show()
    # --------- (2)
)
```

**Some notes:**

- When using pivot, it is recommended to specify the values if you know them so that spark doesn't need to spend time computing the distinct enumerations (more efficient).
- If you `.show()` after (1), it looks like this:

```
+-------+---+----+
|service|low|high|
+-------+---+----+
|      c|  1|null|
|      a|  5|   3|
|      b|  4|   2|
+-------+---+----+
```

- If you `.show()` after (2), then it looks like this (the result you're after):

```
+-------+------------------+
|service|              info|
+-------+------------------+
|      c|         {"low":1}|
|      a|{"low":5,"high":3}|
|      b|{"low":4,"high":2}|
+-------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('service').agg(
  to_json(
    collect_list(
      create_map('usage', 'count')
    )
  ).alias('Info')
).show()
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).